# subprocess.popen working on windows and not on ubuntu

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to create a new process to run another python file using the following code.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python test.py"],shell=True)#,stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT
proc.wait()
```

It works on window but when I tried in an ubuntu console. It would trigger the python console/interpreter instead of running the python file. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to create a minimal, reproducible example (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented the previews answer, do not use `shell=True` if you don't need it, please refer to [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations), there are serious security implication using this option.

working example:

```
╭─root@debi /tmp
╰─# cat 1.py
def main():
  print("ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
╭─root@debi /tmp
╰─# cat 2.py
import subprocess

def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "1.py"])
    proc.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
╭─root@debi /tmp
╰─# python3 2.py
ok
╭─root@debi /tmp
╰─#
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate arguments `python` and `test.py` for the things to work properly:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"],shell=True)
proc.wait()
```

Comment: what is the point of ```shell=True``` are you aware of this ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments at least mention the security implication!